# Не могу найти ошибку в коде. Язык Си

Tags: c

Программа должна выводить два наибольших числа из четырех, заданных с клавиатуры. К сожалению, итогом выполнения кода являются 4 и 2 числа, вне зависимости от их значений. Результат работы закомментированной строки аналогичен ее действующей замене условием IF.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    float k,m,n,s,max,max2;
    printf("Wvedite 4 raznih chisla\n");
    scanf("%f%f%f%f",&k,&m,&n,&s);
    /*max = k>m && k>n && k>s ? k : m>n && m>s ? m : n>s ? n : s;*/
    if (k>m && k>n && k>s) max=k;
    if (m>k && m>n && m>s) max=m;
    if (n>m && n>k && n>s) max=n;
    if (s>m && s>n && s>k) max=s;
    if (max=k) max2=m>n&&m>s?m:n>s?n:s;
    if (max=m) max2=k>n&&k>s?k:n>s?n:s;
    if (max=n) max2=m>k&&m>s?m:k>s?k:s;
    if (max=s) max2=m>n&&m>k?m:n>k?n:k;
    printf("Dva naibol`shih iz nih:\t %8.2f %8.2f",max,max2);
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Древняя ошибка присваивание вместо сравнения. `if (max=k)` => `if (max==k)`

Comment: Вот черт, а ведь я уже попадался на этом пару месяцев назад на плюсах. Бывает же. Огромное спасибо, минут 40 сидел над проблемой)

Comment: @Школьник_1337 Вы бы включили варнинги в настройках компилятора. Он вам должен был показать на эту строчку.